# как быть с нецензурными никами?

Tags: поддержка

что делать, если встречаешь нецензурные слова в именах пользователей? 
[пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185230).

кнопки `тревога` в профиле пользователя не обнаружил.
писать в чат? «проходить мимо»?

Comment: Особенно занятно было бы, если бы его ответ был толковым. По идее, "радовать" нас своим ником он может в вопросах, ответах и комментариях. Если их все удалять, то нигде его ник светиться не будет. Удаление незарегистрированного аккаунта с репутацией 1 вряд ли избавит от новых таких фокусов.

Comment: увы, толковостью ответа он не [блеснул](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/92008/434851#434851). хотя по сути он, может быть, и прав.

Comment: Да, я видел - как-никак первым тревогой отмечал этот ответ я :) Так как SO модерируется всем обществом, то, думаю, с парой-тройкой неадекватов справиться сможем.

Comment: Нужно создать тред-кунсткамеру на мете и складывать всех поехавших туда до того как модератор доберется до них.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Позволительно ли материться на данном сайте?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3490/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В сообществе не должно быть учётных записей с нецензурными или оскорбительными именами пользователя, изображениями учётной записи или другой информацией указанной в профиле. В случае обнаружения подобных участников, пожалуйста, свяжитесь с администрацией любым удобным для вас способом.

Comment: кстати, бывают ещё любители нецензурных аватаров.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Спасибо за замечание, обновил ответ.

Comment: А как связаться с администрацией? Обнаружил подобного пользователя, не совсем приятно видеть такой ник, какой используется у него.

Comment: @DenisBubnov В подвале сайта есть ссылки (горизонтально в ряд). Для отправки отзывов, пожалуйста, используйте ссылку «[связаться с нами](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact)».

Comment: Спасибо. Отправил обращение.