# Позволительно ли материться на данном сайте?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено

Предполагаю, что нет, но вот среди участников данного сайта в их псевдонимах встречаются словечки не особо радующие глаз, в том числе не на русском языке или в виде транслитерации.

Как к этому относится сообщество и администрация?

Comment: А можно примеры? А то некоторым и слово "хрен" не радует глаз, хотя оно не является матерным, а кто-то считает его таковым

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пример в комментарии к ответу написал. P.S. в вопросе именно про матерные имелось в виду.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, все имена со словом на f были сменены. Я также убрал ряд других имен с теми нецензурными английскими словами, которые знаю. Поэтому ставлю [meta-tag:статус-завершено].

Comment: *используйте эвфемизмы, зря что ли в университете учились!*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Использование нецензурной лексики как в сообщениях, так и в псевдонимах на сайте запрещено. В случае обнаружения прецедентов, пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь [обратной связью](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), [чатом](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или [Метой](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all — поиск по английскому слову из 4-х букв на f.

Answer (score 23):

Процитирую [пользовательское соглашение](http://stackexchange.com/legal):

> ### 3. Subscriber Content
>
> ...
>
> Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute
>   any Subscriber Content that ... (d) is libelous, defamatory, abusive,
>   threatening, harassing, hateful, offensive or otherwise violates any
>   law or right of any third party, ...  or (f) remains posted after
>   Subscriber has been notified that such Subscriber Content violates any
>   of sections (a) to (e) of this sentence.

По-русски:

> ### 3. Пользовательский контент
>
> ...
>
> Пользователь понимает, гарантирует и дает согласие, что не будет публиковать  контент, который ... (г) является клеветническим, дискредитирующим, оскорбительным, угрожающим, преследующим, выражающим ненависть, агрессивным или как либо иначе нарушает закон или права третьих лиц, ... или (е) остается опубликованным после уведомления пользователя о нарушении пунктов с (а) по (д).

---

Кроме того, есть [официальная позиция](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites/22233#22233) Джеффа:

> ## No.
>
> Expletives are not acceptable behavior on any Stack Exchange site,
>   even on Meta. There are a very small handful of exceptions (such as if
>   you were talking about the word itself on a language site), but in
>   general you should not use expletives anywhere, under any
>   circumstances. If you can't effectively communicate what you need to
>   say without resorting to lowest common denominator cursing, then keep
>   it to yourself.
>
> If you use expletives, you will get a warning.
>
> If you continue to use expletives, you will be placed on timed
>   suspension.

Перевод:

> ## Нет.
>
> Ругательства неприемлемы на любом сайте Stack Exchange, даже на Мете.
>   Есть совсем немного исключений (например, если вы обсуждаете само
>   слово на сайте, посвященном языку), но в целом вам не следует
>   использовать бранную лексику где бы то ни было ни при каких
>   обстоятельствах. Если вы не способны донести мысль, не прибегая к
>   брани, оставьте ее при себе.
>
> Если вы используете ругательства, вы получите предупреждение.
>
> Если вы не прекратите, то получите временный бан.